# Combination of radioButtons and numericInput for set of values

Tags: r, shiny

At the moment I am using radioButtons to select which set of values is being used.

```
radioButtons("set", "Select your set!",
                     list("Set 1" = "s1",
                          "Set 2" = "s2")
```

Each set has a different value for say "A", "B" and "C".

```
   Set Var Val
1  s1   A  35
2  s1   B  45
3  s1   C  99
4  s2   A  10
5  s2   B  20
6  s2   C  77
```

This works fine for me. In my output I use

```
subset(dat, Set==input$set))
```

**Here is my problem:** 
I would like to add a third radio button that enables you to manually set values for "A", "B" and "C" via numericInput.
Furthermore, the initial values in the respective input fields should be updated from the set that was last selected with the radioButtons.

Comment: so the third radio button should give three text boxes to user and to enter ABC value? If so what's the value of Set in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using `conditionalPanel`. Basically, I always read the selected values from the `numericInput`, but the input is hidden unless `Set 3` is selected. I use a slightly different logic for mapping the values from the inputs (my `data.frame` mapping is in wide format which seems like a better choice IMO) but other than that, this should be applicable to your test code as-is.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  inputPanel(radioButtons(
    "set", "select set", inline = TRUE, 
    list("Set 1" = "s1", "Set 2" = "s2", "Set 3" = "s3")
  )),
  conditionalPanel("input.set == 's3'", inputPanel(
    numericInput("A", "B", 50, 0, 100),
    numericInput("B", "B", 50, 0, 100),
    numericInput("C", "C", 50, 0, 100)
  )),
  verbatimTextOutput("text")
)

mapping <- data.frame(
  row.names = c("s1", "s2"), A = c(35, 10), B = c(45, 20), C = c(99, 77)
)

server <- function(input, output, session){      
  observeEvent(input$set, {
    req(input$set != "s3")
    for(id in c("A", "B", "C"))
      updateNumericInput(session, id, value = mapping[input$set, id])
  })
  output$text <- renderText({paste(input$A, input$B, input$C)})
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

You could also use `renderUI` instead, but `conditionalPanel`s are the better choice for this task.