# radioButtons with numericInput value or vector of values

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to use a `numericInput` value or a prespecified vector of values in a function in `shiny`. I can only supply the `numericInput` value and not the vector when it is selected. A simplified version of what I am doing:

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(a = c(1:3, 3, 3, 6:10), b = c(1, 1, 1, 4:10))
df
#     a  b
# 1   1  1
# 2   2  1
# 3   3  1
# 4   3  4
# 5   3  5
# 6   6  6
# 7   7  7
# 8   8  8
# 9   9  9
# 10 10 10

#demo function to filter one value or vector of values
filter_function <- function(a_value, b_value) {
 df %>% 
    filter(a %in% a_value & b %in% b_value)
}
filter_function(a_value = c(1), b_value = c(1))
filter_function(a_value = c(1, 2, 3), b_value = c(1))

#app
ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(6,
           inputPanel(radioButtons(
             "aset", "select A set", inline = TRUE, 
             list("A set 1" = "as1", "A set 2: 1, 2, 3" = "as2", "A set 3: 3, 4, 5" = "as3"))),
           conditionalPanel("input.aset == 'as1'", inputPanel(
             numericInput(inputId = "apick", "choose", 3, 0, 10),
           )),
           tableOutput('tablefilter')),
    
    column(6, inputPanel(radioButtons(
      "bset", "select B set", inline = TRUE, 
      list("B set 1" = "bs1", "B set 2: 4, 5, 6" = "bs2", "B set 3: 1, 2, 3" = "bs3")
    )),
    conditionalPanel("input.bset == 'bs1'", inputPanel(
      numericInput(inputId = "bpick", "choose", 1, 0, 10),
    )))
    
))


server <- function(input, output, session){      
  output$tablefilter <- renderTable({
    out_df <- filter_function(input$apick, input$bpick) #this needs to capture predefined vectors too
    out_df
    })
}

#vectors to be incorporated
#a_vector_2 <- c(1, 2, 3)
#a_vector_2 <- c(3, 4, 5)
#b_vector_2 <- c(4, 5, 6)
#b_vector_3 <- c(1, 2, 3)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

This works under the default settings but it doesn't work when I click on the predefined vectors as `apick` and `bpick` is only picking up the `numericInput`. Maybe you could do multiple if statements like this but its not what I am after as there would be too much repetition:

```
server <- function(input, output, session){      
  output$tablefilter <- renderTable({
    
    if(input$aset == "as2") {
      out_df <- filter_function(c(1, 2, 3), input$bpick) #this ignores potential vectors in set B 
      return(out_df)
    } else if (input$aset == "as3") {
      out_df <- filter_function(c(3, 4, 5), input$bpick) #this ignores potential vectors in set B 
      return(out_df)
    } #etc etc
  })
  
}
```

Similar to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46933221/4083743) but slightly different.

Any ideas?

thanks

Comment: 'a `numericInput` value or a prespecified vector of values' - What do you mean by this?
I don't understand your question.

Comment: if you select `A set 1`, the user can pick any value via `numericInput` but if they select e.g. `A set 2` then they are selecting a predefined vector of values, `c(1, 2, 3)` in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    radioButtons(
        "set",
        "select A set",
        inline = TRUE,
        choiceNames = list("A Singleton Set",
                           "A Set of 3",
                           "Another Set of 3"),
        # choiceNames are displayed; use choices instead if you want to show the values
        choiceValues = list('Singleton Set', c(1, 2, 3), c(3, 4, 5)) # items in this list will be coerced to strings
    )
    ,
    conditionalPanel("input.set == 'Singleton Set'", inputPanel(
        numericInput(inputId = "singleton", "Enter a number", 1)
    )),
    verbatimTextOutput('console')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    Set <- reactive(eval(parse(text = 
        if (input$set == 'Singleton Set')
            input$singleton
        else
            input$set)))
    output$console <- renderText(Set())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**Edit:** Made the example minimal.

Comment: @user63230 Tell me if this is what you wanted. If yes, I will try to clean it up and generalize it. Your example is reproducible but not minimal.

Comment: this seems to work well, thank you! Interested to see your cleaned up version too